# Installing Theano on EPD (Windows x64)

Tags: python, windows, enthought, theano

I'm trying to install Theano on Enthought Python Distribution (EPD), but I am getting a weird error. Here is what my installation looks like:

- I have installed EPD to `C:\Python27`.
- After that, I have installed `pip` by using `easy_install pip`
- I installed Theano by using `pip install Theano`
- To test, I start `ipython` and type `import theano`. I get the following error:

  ```
  Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
  g++ -shared -g -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -o C:\Users\Ove\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_37_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.2\lazylinker_ext\lazylinker_ext.pyd C:\Users\Ove\AppData\Local\Theano\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_37_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.2\lazylinker_ext\mod.cpp -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27 -lpython27
  C:\Users\Ove\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIoNPlU.o: In function `initlazylinker_ext':C:/Users/Ove/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_37_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.2/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:911: undefined reference to `__imp_Py_InitModule4'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

  Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): C:\Users\Ove\AppData\Local\Temp. C:/Users/Ove/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_37_Stepping_5_GenuineIntel-2.7.2/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:911: undefi. collect2: ld returned 1 exit status4'
  ```

Does anyone know how to get Theano to run with EPD?

Comment: If I install the 32-bit version of EPD and follow the same steps, theano works. This means something is wrong with the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last release of Theano(0.5) has some problem on Windows. You need to install the bleeding edge version. You can update your version  like this:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

This should solve the problem. If not, you probably have some conflict with a different installation of gcc. Do you have installed it with cygwin or mingw? EPD installs its own version of mingw.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I have to add that I had to install git for windows in order to get theano from its repository.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get Theano working with Enthought, but using the Anaconda python distribution I eventually got it working. Here's how:

- uninstall Enthought and any other python version (start from scratch)
- download and install Anaconda python distribution from this link:    http://09c8d0b2229f813c1b93-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.r79.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-1.5.0-Windows-x86_64.exe and click the option to use Anaconda as your default python version
- to get the academic license, go to this page: https://store.continuum.io/cshop/academicanaconda and click the "free" button next to Anaconda Academic License (right side of page)
- you should receive an email with an academic license .txt file. Follow the instructions in the email to place the file in the correct directory, and run several command-line commands to update anaconda and install numpy and scipy
- open a windows command prompt and    type

  pip install theano
- create a file .theanorc.txt containing the lines:

  [global]
  openmp=False

  [blas]
  ldflags=
- place .theanorc.txt in your home folder (the folder for your user account)
- make sure the following paths are added to your PATH environment variable:

  C:\Anaconda\MinGW\bin;
  C:\Anaconda\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib;
  C:\Anaconda;
  C:\Anaconda\Scripts;