# How do I install theano in Anaconda ver. 2.1 Windows 64 bit for Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, theano, conda

I've installed [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_%28Python_distribution%29). Now I want to install the Theano library in Anaconda. I have tried:

1. The Theano installer for Anaconda from http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#windows-installer-for-anacondace, but it raises error "The installer could not find a version of Anaconda installed. Please download and install Anaconda CE". I have added ~/anaconda3, ~/anaconda3/scripts to the environment variable path.
2. I have tried to install it by building the package as mentioned on Stack Overflow, *[How do I keep track of pip-installed packages in an Anaconda (Conda) environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640305)*, but this also fails during the testing of package. The error screenshot is below:

[image: Theano error message]

I have even installed Python ver. 3.4, installed Theano using pip install, and when I tried to import Theano it gave an error similar to the error in the screen shot. I tried the changes mentioned in this [Google Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups) discussion, **[Re: [theano-users] Install Theano on Windows for Python 3](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/theano-users/RcANq0NQgPE/IQMHD3mggi0J)**, but no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Theano on EPD (Windows x64)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270871/installing-theano-on-epd-windows-x64)

Comment: @Moes, I don't recall that link solving my problem with installing Theano on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Running Theano on Python 3.4 is complicated. So far I would recommend that you run Theano in Python 2.7. The libraries written for Theano are Python 2.6+ based. So in order to get Theano running in Python 3.4, you would be needing the 2to3 automated python 2 to 3 code translation tool. I haven't tested Theano using 2to3, so I can't comment on whether it would work or not. But, I am using Python 2.7 and Theano works smoothly. Also, you might want to use AnacondaCE with Python 2.7 installer which pretty much gives you everything you need to start developing.

You would also need to reinstall Theano using

```
pip install Theano
```

Answer (score 1):

As we can see, you have tried to use Theano under Windows. Please, ensure that you have a [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) compiler. Further, ensure that you have MinGW and libpython packages.

Generally, I recommend to use the answer *[How do I install Keras and Theano in Anaconda Python 2.7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097988/how-to-install-keras-and-theano-in-anaconda-python-2-7-in-windows/34975902#34975902)*, but without the last step.

Answer (score 1):

I could never get a working installation of Theano using Anaconda with Python 3.4, and I also could never get the manual installation working with MinGW, but I was able to get it working flawlessly using WinPython 3.4.

**Theano Installation and Configuration on Windows 10 with GPU Acceleration and Python 3.4**

If you're using Windows, Theano can be tricky to install and configure. I was able to get it working by following a combination of these tutorials:

- [Installing Keras and Theano with GPU-acceleration on Windows 10](http://ankivil.com/installing-keras-theano-and-dependencies-on-windows-10/)
- [Making Theano faster on Windows 10 with CuDNN and CNMeM](http://ankivil.com/making-theano-faster-with-cudnn-and-cnmem-on-windows-10/)
- [Official Theano installation instructions for Windows](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/install_windows.html)

**Easier configuration of Theano with Python 3.4 using WinPython instead of Anaconda Python**

It was much easier to get Theano working on Python 3.4 when using [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) instead of [Anaconda Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), but WinPython stores environment settings in its settings directory (e.g. `C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\settings\.keras\`) rather than looking in your `%USERPROFILE%` for the keras.json file when you're wanting it to pick up your environment settings (as explained in the setup guides). Also, if you are still having trouble, you might just need to set the `THEANO_FLAGS` system environment variable to something like this: `floatX=float32,device=gpu,nvcc.fastmath=True,lib.cnmem=0.8,blas.ldflags=-LC:\src\OpenBLAS -lopenblas`. (Note that this environment variable overrides the settings in any .theanorc setup file as detailed [here in the Theano configuration documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html) except if using WinPython, the .theanorc file would go into `C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\settings\.theanorc` rather than `%USERPROFILE\.theanorc`.)

When installing Theano with WinPython, installation is much easier if you use the suggested Theano installation location (`C:\SciSoft\`). In that case, your installation directory should look like this:

[image: Picture of SciSoft installation directory]

**Fixing bugs in Theano environment batch file when using WinPython**

The other issue I ran into with the Theano installation guides is that the batch script had some bugs in it that were causing the dependency paths to be incorrect. Here was my final version of the `env.bat` file:

```
REM configuration of paths
set VSFORPYTHON="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC"
set SCISOFT=%~dp0

REM add tdm gcc stuff
set PATH=%SCISOFT%TDM-GCC-64\bin;%SCISOFT%TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin;%PATH%

REM add winpython stuff
CALL %SCISOFT%WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\scripts\env.bat

REM configure path for msvc compilers
REM for a 32 bit installation change this line to
REM CALL %VSFORPYTHON%\vcvarsall.bat
CALL %VSFORPYTHON%\vcvarsall.bat amd64

REM return a shell
cmd.exe /k
```

If using Theano, your .keras file will need to be setup like:

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "image_dim_ordering": "th",
    "backend": "theano" 
}
```

**Issue with installing CuDNN**

Another key thing was that the CuDNN DLLs need to be copied into their corresponding folders in the CUDA installation directory in order for them to be detected. Instructions are detailed here: [Instructions for installing CuDNN into CUDA on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248056/how-to-setup-cudnn-with-theano-on-windows-7-64-bit)

**If still having issues with Theano installation on Windows with Python 3.4:**

Then please review the information here: [Full installation guide for Theano on Windows with Python 3.4, including all required environment variables and PATH directories](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/3376)

**Another key issue with installing the C++ dependencies for Theano**

Another thing I was tripped up by is that in the [official Theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano_versions/dev/install_windows.html), it provides very specific instructions on installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). It seems to be that this compiler is also required to be installed *in exactly the way that the Theano documentation specifies to perform the installation on the command line* to get Python 3.4 to work. I will quote the official Theano documentation, which states:

> 1. open an administrator’s console (got to `start`, then type `cmd`,
>    right-click on the command prompt icon and select `run as administrator`)
> 2. `cd` to your downloads directory and execute `msiexec /i VCForPython27.msi ALLUSERS=1`

**General advice about GPU-acceleration**

And FYI, if you haven't tried configuring a neural network library, I highly recommend that you use GPU-acceleration.