# Cannot create neural network model in Keras (In Windows)

Tags: windows, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras

I have installed Keras and using Theano as backend.

I am getting this error, when trying to develop simple Neural Network Model;

> ImportError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node',
>   Elemwise{Composite{EQ(i0, RoundHalfAwayFromZero(i1))}}(dense_3_target,
>   Elemwise{Composite{scalar_sigmoid((i0 + i1))}}[(0, 0)].0), '\n', 'DLL
>   load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.',
>   '[Elemwise{Composite{EQ(i0,
>   RoundHalfAwayFromZero(i1))}}(dense_3_target, )]')

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Innocent

Comment: Could you add a code which is producing your error? Without this it's hard to help you in any way :)

Comment: Hi Marcin, thank you for looking at it. I resolved the issue using this link; https://dnc1994.com/2016/03/installing-xgboost-on-windows/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install theano in Anaconda ver. 2.1 Windows 64 bit for Python 3.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629347/how-do-i-install-theano-in-anaconda-ver-2-1-windows-64-bit-for-python-3-4)

Comment: @devinbost please stop flagging questions as duplicate when they're at best borderline, and at worst completely different. This is getting very difficult.