# Installing Theano and Keras on my Windows 10 Workstation

Tags: python, cygwin, anaconda, theano, keras

I am trying to use Keras to develop a Neural Network in Python, after managing to install on my Windows 10 Workstation Anaconda3 (with all its libraries: numpy, scikit-learn, pandas, SciPy and matplotlib), I realized to need TensorFlow or Theano, too.

After I failed intalling TensorFlow, I downloaded and was able to install Theano, but trying to import it from the Python prompt, I received the following:

> `WARNING: "g ++ not detected! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be several degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string"`

Hoping in this way to solve the problem, I downloaded the GNU compiler for C++ Cygwin64, but nothing has changed, at all! Acknowledge that this is really the right way to move forward, how should I access the "Theano flags cxx"?

Comment: Can you explain how you installed TensorFlow and Theano?

Comment: About TensorFlow I don't rmember. To install Theano I opened CygWin64 Terminal & wrote "pip install Theano". Everything was Ok, at the end of the process...

Comment: When using conda/Anaconda, you should use `conda install <package>` generally, especially for packages like Theano and TensorFlow that have compiled C++ libraries. You should run the `conda install` command from the Windows command prompt, not the Cygwin terminal (unless you installed Anaconda in Cygwin). Make sure to run `pip uninstall Theano` before you install using conda.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install theano in Anaconda ver. 2.1 Windows 64 bit for Python 3.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629347/how-do-i-install-theano-in-anaconda-ver-2-1-windows-64-bit-for-python-3-4)

Answer (score 1):

first, its only performance issue to run theano without g++. it a warning and not exception when importing it.

BUT probably you want performance when using deep learning lib like keras so lets try fix the theano installation.

please follow the [theano docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html) about installing theano on windows. you might want to clean previous installation of requirements.

to install the gcc follow [this section](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#gcc) which says:

> Theano C code compiler currently requires a GCC installation. We have
>   used the **build TDM GCC** which is provided for both 32- and 64-bit
>   platforms...

download from [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) follow the installation instruction.

### Tensorflow

I recommending working with `tensorflow` as `keras` recently changed the default backend from `theano` to tensorflow.

using `anaconda` and `pip` you should easily do `pip install tensorflow` and it will work.

actually today I just installed `keras` and `tensorflow` on windows 10 using anaconda by just running `pip install keras tensorflow` so I suggest you try fresh clean installation of anaconda and python and try this again.

please update if you succeed or having another issues installing theano / tensorflow / keras

Comment: Thanks a lot! Doing what you have written (but launching the Anaconda prompt with Administrator privilege!) I had the following results: (1) Successfully installed protobuf-3.1.0.post1 tensorflow-0.12.1; (2) Successfully built keras
Installing collected packages: theano, keras
Successfully installed keras-1.2.1 theano-0.8.2

Comment: great, consider approving the answer or adding more info if the issue is still not fixed