# Installing Theano with Canopy EPD on windows 7, 64 bit

Tags: python, windows, theano, canopy

I have successfully installed theano on Canopy EPD, windows 7, 64 bit. While importing theano (for testing at first time), I am getting this error. Can anybody help. Thanks.

It is similar to this question:
[Installing Theano on EPD (Windows x64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270871/installing-theano-on-epd-windows-x64)

```
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In function unpack_list_of_ssize_t':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:58: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_TypeError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:68: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In functionCLazyLinker_init':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:341: undefined reference to __imp_PyCObject_Type'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:362: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:380: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:395: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:399: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:403: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o:C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:407: more undefined references to __imp_PyExc_IndexError' follow. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In functionCLazyLinker_init':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:415: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_TypeError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:430: undefined reference to__imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:436: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:450: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_TypeError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:454: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In functionc_call':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:555: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:555: undefined reference to__imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:555: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:556: undefined reference to__imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o:C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:556: more undefined references to __imp__Py_NoneStruct' follow. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In functionlazy_rec_eval':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:628: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:651: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_TypeError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:659: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_ValueError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:667: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_IndexError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:718: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:725: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_TypeError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:731: undefined reference to __imp_PyExc_TypeError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:781: undefined reference to__imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:781: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:782: undefined reference to__imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In function CLazyLinker_call':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:817: undefined reference to__imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:817: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o:C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:818: more undefined references to__imp__Py_NoneStruct' follow. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In function CLazyLinker_call':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:867: undefined reference to__imp_PyExc_AssertionError'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:910: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:910: undefined reference to__imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:911: undefined reference to __imp__Py_NoneStruct'. C:\Users\HARISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccLHOaX7.o: In functionCLazyLinker_set_allow_gc':. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:943: undefined reference to __imp_PyBool_Type'. C:/Users/Harish-Chandra/AppData/Local/Theano/compiledir_Windows-8-6.2.9200-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-2.7.9-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:946: undefined reference to__imp__Py_TrueStruct'. collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your C++ compiler. You mention that your question is similar to the referenced question but don't explain why the answers to that other question don't answer your question. More detail please!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Theano on EPD (Windows x64)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270871/installing-theano-on-epd-windows-x64)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question wasnt properly closed by the author and it's also relevant to most EPD users, including me when i first started with EPD + theano, i will answer to it.

First, remove any other python environment if possible.
Be sure there is no other conflicting environment path of python, just in case.

**1.Install EPD CANOPY**

**2.Install the MinGW package that is on package installer available on Canopy application**

That should be easy to do, you just open the package manager from inside the Canopy application.

**3.Install Theano from inside EPD**

**Before** you go spamming

pip install --upgrade  --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git

in every prompt of command you see, **DONT DO IT**.

--
**Instead, Open Canopy.**

In Canopy screen, go to **"Tools"**, and then **open "Canopy Command Prompt"**

A screen exactly like the CMD from windows will open.

On that screen, **execute** :

**pip install --upgrade  --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git**

Should work fine now.

--

However, dont forget you will need , obviously the Windows SDK , depending on the windows version of course.
You can try installing the last Visual Studio with comes with everything you need.

If you need more info on this, check this related Stackoverflow topic :

[Installing theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630020/installing-theano/37780769#37780769)